# Is there a way to combine paths if a directory has only a single file in ranger file manager?

Tags: file-manager

Say, the directory structure is like:

- main_dir

  - sub_dir1

    - single_dir

      - single_file
  - sub_dir2

    - some_file
    - another_file
    - more_files_and_dirs

In ranger file manager, considering there are three panes. The first pane shows contents at the level of main_dir. Given that main_dir is highlighted, the second pane then shows sub_dir1 and sub_dir2. If sub_dir1 is highlighted, single_dir is shown in third pane else if sub_dir2 is highlighted, then some_file, etc. are shown.

In cases where there are multiple directories like sub_dir1 which have just a single file nested deep, it is tedious to navigate to and again. Is it possible to shrink or combine the paths of different levels if only a single content is present in the next directory level? For example, second pane shows sub_dir1/single_dir/single_file instead of showing single_file in the third pane. This way, it would be easy to navigate single directory nested hierarchies.

In case, more files are present in single_dir. Then, second pane shows sub_dir1/single_dir and third pane shows single_file and more_files.

Is there a way to do this by changing the config? Dired in emacs supported these using [dired-collapse](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks#dired-collapse). I am looking for a similar functionality in ranger.

I tried looking up the issues of the ranger repo and a quick google search to check if I can find something related. This did not yield any related results.

Comment: Are you talking about this [ranger file manager](https://github.com/ranger/ranger)?

Comment: Yes! And I just ran into :flat which accomplishes something similar but it is not persistent, in the sense, the next time I open ranger and navigate to the folder I have to use :flat again. Further, flat clutters the panel by adding these combined paths on top of the separate ones, instead of overwriting. meaning, now both sub_dir1 and sub_dir1/single_dir/single_file are shown.